# Select with IN and Like

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a very interesting problem. I have an SSRS report with a multiple select drop down.
The drop down allows to select more than one value, or all values.
All values is not the problem.

The problem is 1 or the combination of more than 1 option

When I select in the drop down 'AAA' it should return 3 values:  'AAA','AAA 1','AAA 2'

Right now is only returning 1 value.

**QUESTION:**

How can make the IN statement work like a LIKE?

```
The Drop down select

SELECT '(All)' AS team, '(All)' AS Descr 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA' , 'AAA' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'BBB' , 'BBB'  


Table Mytable

ColumnA Varchar(5)

Values for ColumnA
'AAA'
'AAA 1'
'AAA 2'
'BBB'
'BBB 1'
'BBB 2'


SELECT * FROM Mytable
WHERE ColumnA IN (SELECT * FROM SplitListString(@Team, ',')))


Split function

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitListString]
 (@InputString NVARCHAR(max), @SplitChar CHAR(1))
 RETURNS @ValuesList TABLE
 (
 param NVARCHAR(MAX)
 )
 AS
 BEGIN

    DECLARE @ListValue     NVARCHAR(max)
    DECLARE @TmpString     NVARCHAR(max) 
    DECLARE @PosSeparator  INT  
    DECLARE @EndValues     BIT

    SET @TmpString = LTRIM(RTRIM(@InputString));
    SET @EndValues = 0

    WHILE (@EndValues = 0) BEGIN
        SET @PosSeparator = CHARINDEX(@SplitChar, @TmpString)

        IF (@PosSeparator) > 1 BEGIN
            SELECT @ListValue = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@TmpString, 1, @PosSeparator -1 )))
        END
        ELSE BEGIN
            SELECT @ListValue = LTRIM(RTRIM(@TmpString))
            SET @EndValues = 1
        END

        IF LEN(@ListValue) > 0 BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @ValuesList
            SELECT @ListValue       
        END

        SET @TmpString = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@TmpString, @PosSeparator + 1, LEN(@TmpString) - @PosSeparator)))
    END

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: Can you post a bit of `SplitListString()`? Also, this may be a stretch, but your values aren't all 3 characters long followed by a digit?

Comment: I could but it will not make a difference since the problem is in the select and where clause. The split string only creates a table separated by commas

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  But, you can make the like work like the like:

```
select *
from mytable t join
     SplitListString(@Team, ',') s
     on t.ColumnA like '%'+s.param+'%'
```

That is, move the split list to an explicit join.  Replace  with the actual column name returned by the function, and use the like function.

Or, if you prefer:

```
select *
from mytable t cross join
     SplitListString(@Team, ',') s
where t.ColumnA like '%'+s.param+'%'
```

The two versions are equivalent and should produce the same execution plan.

Comment: It will be very hard to do a join. This has to go in the where clause

Comment: Yes, if they select "ALL" then there is not need to JOIN.

Comment: @InternetEngineer . . . if you prefer to cross join and put the condition in the WHERE clause, you can do that.  You don't need to.  The query works either way.

Comment: @Tamir . . . The question is explicitly about functionaltiy, not performance.  This is how you can make the "IN" into a "LIKE".  Each comparison requires a separate pass through the data table, and indexes can't be used.  Whether this is acceptable or not seems unrelated to how it can be done.

Comment: Gordon, if a function works, but takes an hour to run, it's not a solution to the problem.  No user is going to wait around that long to get results back from a report.  Performance is a key part of the functionality here.

Comment: What happens when they select 2 values?

Comment: @Jim . . . I'll let the person who wrote the question be the judge of what is important.  The performance is quite likely fine, depending on the size of the data.  The question makes *no* reference at all to performance, and yet it does directly ask for multiple "LIKE"s.  You should let the answer'er address the issue of performance, since it may be a total non-issue.

Comment: I have posted the split function

Comment: @InternetEngineer . . . presumably the two values get put into Team separated by commas.  Each is then compared to the underlying data using LIKE.

Comment: Maybe I don't need to split them at all

Comment: @InternetEngineer . . . .suggestion:  ask another question, and give more information about what you are trying to do.  There might be a better way to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Better approach would be to have a TeamsTable (teamID, teamName, ...) and teamMembersTable (teamMemberID, teamID, teamMemberDetails, ...).
Then you an build your dropdown list as
`SELECT ... FROM TeamsTable ...;`
and
`SELECT ... FROM teamMembersTable WHERE teamID IN (valueFromYourDropDown);`

Or you can just store your teamID or teamName (or both) in your (equivalent of) teamMembersTable

Comment: This does not work as the drop down allows multiple selections and the target table needs to do a like search.

Comment: I misspelled that, code above should have read: `teamID IN (valuesFromYourDropDown);` (multiple valueS) - this was the reason for IN clause.   From parts of your code I assumed (possibly incorrectly) that you have a drop-down of teams/groups and then you want to look for "members" of these teams/groups. If that **IS** the intention than storing a groupID/Name on each record **IS** the best way of doing it. This way you can add more groups and re-group existing members just by manipulating data in your table(s).

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to get IN to work the same as LIKE without a lot of work.  You could do something like this though (and it would be nice to see some of your actual data though so we could give better solutions):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE LEFT(field,3) IN @Parameter
```

If you'd like better performance, create a code field on your table and update it like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET codeField = LEFT(field,3)
```

Then just add an index on that field and run this query to get your results:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE codeField IN @Parameter
```

Comment: The data I placed in the sample is very close to the real thing.

Comment: Ok, so if you have a set number of items in your drop down, and you're looking for fields that start with those items, then I don't see why what Germann or I suggested wouldn't work.